# clicking a link cause running a view

Tags: python, django

I have a view for logout,now I wanna when user click on an anchor link the logout view run,how can I do this?
in views.py:

```
def logout(request):
   auth.logout(request)
   return render_to_response("airAgency/index.html")
```

Comment: Er, what? You want to know how to create a link?

Comment: I have a link in my template,I wanna when user click it,the login view run,I don't wanna use form with a submit button.

Comment: I'm new in django,I can submit a form and run a view for that,but I don't now what should I do to run s.th like logout view when clicking an anchor link.

Comment: How will the server get your data if you don't use a form? If you want to logout on the click of a link you just put the URL that corresponds to your Logout view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm new in django,I can submit a form and run a view for that, but I
>   don't now what should I do to run s.th like logout view when clicking
>   an anchor link.

Logging out via a link instead of a form is easy.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.logout

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return http.HttpResponse("You've been logged out")
```

Just point a url to this view like you did with your form and go to that URL.